# Unexpected lazy value lastNoSuccessVar in trait Parsers

Tags: scala

Could you please advise what lazy value is all about here?..

```
  [ERROR] ## Exception when compiling 284 sources to C:\LocalFolder\dev\project-buckets\OFP\project\target\classes
  java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
    unexpected lazy value lastNoSuccessVar in trait Parsers <mutable> lazy <expandedname> private[this]
       while compiling: C:\LocalFolder\dev\project-buckets\OFP\project\target\generated-sources\scalaxb\com\project\tec\ofp\job\indox\agreement\protocol\xmlprotocol.scala
          during phase: mixin
       library version: version 2.13.6
      compiler version: version 2.13.6
    reconstructed args: ...

    last tree to typer: Ident(isNotValid)
         tree position: line 300 of C:\LocalFolder\dev\project-buckets\OFP\project\src\com\project\tec\ofp\job\indox\agreement\validation\rules\ContentRulesWrapper.scala
              tree tpe: runtime.BooleanRef
                symbol: variable isNotValid
     symbol definition: var isNotValid: runtime.BooleanRef (a TermSymbol)
        symbol package: com.project.tec.ofp.job.indox.agreement.validation.rules
         symbol owners: variable isNotValid -> method $anonfun$EX_CSA_15$9 -> object ContentRulesWrapper
             call site: <$anon: com.project.tec.ofp.job.indox.agreement.protocol.XMLProtocol$DefaultCommusitecofpjobindoxagreementcsa_LinkedIdentifiersFormat> in package protocol in package protocol

  == Source file context for tree position ==

     297     deliverMap.map(f => {
     298       var isNotValid: Boolean = false
     299       f._2.foreach(f => if (f == "Refer to Agreement" | f == "") isNotValid = true)
     300       if (isNotValid) f._1
     301     }).mkString("|")
     302 
     303     val isRaised: Boolean = RulesDef.EX_CSA_15(deliverMap)
  scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.throwAssertionError(SymbolTable.scala:171)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin.$anonfun$publicizeTraitMethods$2(Mixin.scala:237)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin.$anonfun$publicizeTraitMethods$2$adapted(Mixin.scala:233)
  scala.reflect.internal.Scopes$Scope.foreach(Scopes.scala:455)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin.publicizeTraitMethods(Mixin.scala:233)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin.$anonfun$addMixedinMembers$12(Mixin.scala:404)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin.$anonfun$addMixedinMembers$12$adapted(Mixin.scala:401)
  scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:563)
  scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:561)
  scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:919)
  scala.collection.IterableOps$WithFilter.foreach(Iterable.scala:889)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin.addMixedinMembers(Mixin.scala:401)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin$MixinTransformer.preTransform(Mixin.scala:440)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin$MixinTransformer.transform(Mixin.scala:650)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin$MixinTransformer.transform(Mixin.scala:415)
  scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTemplate(Trees.scala:2595)
  scala.reflect.internal.Trees$ClassDef.$anonfun$transform$2(Trees.scala:361)
  scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2633)
  scala.reflect.internal.Trees$ClassDef.transform(Trees.scala:360)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin$MixinTransformer.transform(Mixin.scala:650)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin$MixinTransformer.transform(Mixin.scala:415)
  scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(Trees.scala:2622)
  scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2620)
  scala.reflect.internal.Trees$PackageDef.$anonfun$transform$1(Trees.scala:342)
  scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2633)
  scala.reflect.internal.Trees$PackageDef.transform(Trees.scala:342)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Mixin$MixinTransformer.transform(Mixin.scala:650)
  scala.tools.nsc.ast.Trees$Transformer.transformUnit(Trees.scala:183)
  scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform$Phase.apply(Transform.scala:32)
  scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:454)
  scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:401)
  scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1519)
  scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1503)
  scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1495)
  scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileFiles(Global.scala:1609)
  xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerBridge.scala:163)
  xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerBridge.scala:134)
  xsbt.CompilerBridge.run(CompilerBridge.scala:39)
  sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:91)
  sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$7(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:192)
  scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
  sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:247)
  sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:182)
  sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:163)
  sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:239)
  sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:163)
  sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:210)
  sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:528)
  sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:528)
  sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$apply$5(Incremental.scala:175)
  sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$apply$5$adapted(Incremental.scala:173)
  sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$$anon$2.run(Incremental.scala:459)
  sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$CycleState.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:116)
  sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$$anon$1.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:56)
  sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$$anon$1.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:52)
  sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:263)
  sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$incrementalCompile$8(Incremental.scala:414)
  sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.withClassfileManager(Incremental.scala:501)
  sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.incrementalCompile(Incremental.scala:401)
  sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.apply(Incremental.scala:167)
  sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:528)
  sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:482)
  sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:332)
  sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:420)
  sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:137)
  sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompiler.compile(SbtIncrementalCompiler.java:179)
  scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.incrementalCompile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:365)
  scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:122)
  scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:89)
  scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute(ScalaMojoSupport.java:305)
  org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
  org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
  org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
  org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
             
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time:  49.546 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-01T18:57:23+02:00
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Not enough code context to reproduce the error. Instead of a big error-text dump, you might post a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: we are talking about compilation issue, don't we? The code which failed to compile and the context included in the error. not enough for cool scala dev to fix compilation issue?

Comment: what reproducible example are you talking about? this is compilation issue, not runtime issue...

Comment: A compiler issue needs a way to reproduce it 100% as much as a runtime issue does. Also, your aggressive and sarcastic attitude reflects poorly on you and it isn't going to make anyone want to spend their free time helping you.

Comment: @SethTisue I don't agree with you that 'compiler issue needs a way to reproduce it 100% as much as a runtime issue does', but I don't want to discuss it here.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments suggest, more information will help people understand what the problem is and allow people to help. I've taken a best guess at the types involved and you could try the following:

```scala
val deliverMap: Seq[(String, Seq[String])] = ???
deliverMap.map(f => {
      val isNotValid = f._2.exists(f => f == "Refer to Agreement" || f.isEmpty)
      if (isNotValid) f._1 else ""
     }).mkString("|")
```

Some of the reasons the code from the error won't compile which immediately jump out:

- You need to use `||` instead of `|` for an `or` expression
- The line `if (isNotValid) f._1` doesn't not return anything in the case that `isNotValid` is `false`. In Scala just about everything is an expression which returns a value.